# Azure CosmosDB with MongoDB API: how to avoid request rate is large errors

Tags: node.js, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

We're using a specific instance of Azure CosmosDB which has MongoDB API support.

I use a library called es6-promise-pool to limit concurrency (I've turned it down to 1).

```
function updateLoglineDB(outArr, brbId, context) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let concurrency = 1;
        const promiseIterator = generatePromisesLoglines(outArr, brbId, context);
        let pool = new PromisePool(promiseIterator, concurrency);

        pool.start().then((done) => {
            resolve(done);
        }).catch((err) => {
            reject(err);
        });
    });
}
```

Here is the generatePromisesLoglines function:

```
const generatePromisesLoglines = function * (outArr, brbId, context) {
    for (let entry of outArr) {
        yield promiseWrite(entry, brbId, context);
    }
};
```

Here is the promiseWrite function:

```
function promiseWrite(entry, brbId, context) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let loglineColl = db.get().collection(logLinesCollection);
        loglineColl.update({ _id: entry._id }, {$set: entry}, {upsert: true}, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                context.log(brbId, ': ', err);
                reject(`logline write rejected with error ${err}, ${brbId}, ${entry}`);
            } else {
                resolve(`result of update: ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

I've looked for a bulk insert function, but I've not found any bulk insert or bulk updates, according to this webpage: [Azure Cosmos DB Mongo API support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-feature-support)

The request rate is large error occurs when I am trying to insert ~15-20k documents at once.  Is there a better way I could write this, or some kind of supported bulk insert for the MongoDB API to Azure CosmosDB that I could use?

I created a test database with sharding with 100,000 RUs, I don't think it should require more as each individual document is relatively small.

Sample document:

```
{
    "_id" : "1456026|<filename>|8842",
    "signatureGroup" : "<teamName>",
    "brbId" : "145602",
    "file" : "<filename>",
    "lineNumber" : 8842,
    "line" : "<sample logline> ~200-300 characters",
    "date" : ISODate("2018-05-14T20:15:13.771Z"),
    "matchCode" : "<sample matchCode>",
    "info" : false
}
```